# Trigger ADO Pipeline using uri ansible failed with 302 error

Tags: ansible, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using ansible uri to trigger an ado pipeline with the following code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Trigger az pipeline
      uri:
        url: https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/pipelines/47/runs?&api-version=6.1
        method: POST
        body_format: json
        status_code: [200]
        return_content: true
        user: "username"
        password: "token"
        headers:
            Content-Type: application/json
            Accept: application/json
            Authorization: "Basic token"
        body: >-
            {
                "definition": {"id": 47},
                "stagesToSkip": ["DEV"] 
            }
      register: output
    - debug:
        var: output
```

I have an 302 error:

```
................
.........
"msg": "Status code was 302 and not [200]: HTTP Error 302: Found", ........................................
..................
```

The same code worked fine before but when I have changed the token I have this issue. My token have full access.

Thank you

Comment: Well, what's in the 302's body? What's the URL it 302s to? What happens if you issues that same request outside of ansible, e.g. using `curl`?

Comment: Err, and I just noticed you have both `username: & password:` **AND** an `Authorization: Bearer` header, and that's almost certainly not going to do what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `force_basic_auth: true`. Strange behavior from ansible.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation of the [`uri`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) module, to address an [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) with [HTTP Status Code 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) message

```
Status code was 302 and not [200]: HTTP Error 302: Found
```

you'll need to introduce the Parameter [`follow_redirects`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-follow_redirects) with `all` and maybe an additional [`status_code`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-status_code) since it has `200` as default only.

> *The same code worked fine before but when I have changed the token I have this issue. My token have full access.*

A possible reason can be if the authentication failed the request gets redirected to the login page.